# ArrayList<String> to toString()

Tags: java, arraylist, tostring

Im having trouble printing the ArrayList through to the toString. It says that I can not convert an ArrayList to an String. Here my code if anyone can help.

```
package edu.purse.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Purse 
  {
    ArrayList<String> coins = new ArrayList<String>();
    public Purse()
    {
    }
  public void addCoin(String coinName)
  {
    coins.add(coinName);
  }
  public String toString()
  {
      return  coins;
  }
}

package edu.purse.test;

public class PurseTester {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Purse p = new Purse();
    p.addCoin("Quarter");
    p.addCoin("Dime");
    System.out.println(p.toString());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You are returning an `ArrayList` when the method declares the return type as `String`. Use

```
public String toString()
{
    return coins.toString();
}
```

---

Note that explicitly calling `toString()` here

```
System.out.println(p.toString());
```

is unnecessary. There's an overloaded method that accepts an `Object` argument and internally calls `toString()`, a method that each class inherits from `Object`, a class which all classes implicitly `extend` in Java.

Comment: Thank you very much man. It helps alot having you kind of people around!

Comment: @Chance You're welcome. Consider accepting this or other (they all deleted...) answers to help make Stackoverflow go round.